# Style table to highligh every other 2 rows

Tags: css

I've been reading about css3's nth-child, but can't figure out how I can style a table where 
rows 3,4 | 7,8 | 11,12 | 15,16  etc. are yellow. 
Basically every other 2 rows are styled.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine following:

- *every 4th row starting from 3rd one*, which is `nth-child(4n+3)`
- *every 4th row starting from 4th one* (`nth-child(4n+4)`) - it can also be just `nth-child(4n)`:

```
table tr:nth-child(4n+3) td, table tr:nth-child(4n+4) td {
    background: red;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KANT7/)